# display vs. setNeedsDisplay

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, quartz-2d

I noticed a strange problem with my Cocoa-based application on Mac OS X 10.7.
Due to some reason (not important here) sometimes I have to draw outside of drawRect method of my custom view.

I have to call lockFocus/lockFocusIfCanDraw on my view, ask for the current context, do actual drawing with CGContext family of functions (CoreGrapchis), and at the end do CGContextFlush (I can also flush a window, or use NSGraphicsContext class method to do a flush).

This sequence is actually the same as if I'm calling -display method of NSView.

The problem is ... it's 3-4 times slower, than "natural" way (call setNeedsDisplay or draw from drawRect when Cocoa asks you to do this).
I can not simply call, for example, setNeedsDisplay for a view, I need this '-display - like' functionality.

In a test example (which uses timer), for the simplicity, I'm calling -display (since it does in general the same work my app does) vs -setNeedsDisplay and I can see the timing of '-display' is 3-4 times longer than of '-setNeedsDisplay'.

Here is an example of my CustomView class (implementation):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView
{
   CFTimeInterval startTime;
   NSTimer *timer;
   unsigned step;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    return [super initWithFrame : frame];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   CGContextRef ctx = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

   if(!timer)
   {
      CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1., 1., 1., 1.);
      CGContextFillRect(ctx, dirtyRect);
   }
   else
   {
      CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0., 0., 0., 1.);
      CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(step * 1.5, 100, 2., 2.));
   }
}

- (void) mouseDown : (NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   if (!timer)
   {
      startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
      timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval : 0.006 target : self selector : @selector(handleTimer:) userInfo : nil repeats : YES];
      step = 0;
   }
}

- (void) handleTimer : (NSTimer *) dummy
{
   if(step < 200)
   {
      ++step;
#if 1
      [self display];
#else
      [self setNeedsDisplay : YES];
#endif
   }
   else 
   {
      [timer invalidate];
      timer = nil;
      NSLog(@"animation time is: %g", CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime);
   }
}

@end
```

I think even if CACurrentMediaTime is not really good function for my purpose, it still can show the obvious time difference (and it's easy to notice without any measurements - display is really slow).
handleTimer method has two sections - if you change '1' to '0' in pp-directive you can try both -display/-setNeedsDisplay. So, I have, for example the following output:

-display: 3.32 s. (?)

-setNeedsDisplay: 1.2 s.

I had a look at call tree/time spent, produced by 'Instruments' app, but it did not help me much.

Edit:
**Hmmmm, I can see now: actually, with setNeedsDisplay view is not re-drawn on every timer event!**

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to drop down to the CG functions in your drawRect method.

This code is equivalent:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   if(!timer)
   {
      [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
      NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
   }
   else
   {
      [[NSColor blackColor] set];
       NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(step * 1.5, 100.0, 2.0, 2.0));
   }
}
```

As for -display and -setNeedsDisplay, the former makes the drawing happen immediately, the latter sets a flag, and each time through the event loop, if that flag is true, the window will send -display to the view in question and clear the flag.

One more thing: this approach of using an NSTimer to drive an animation is a bit out of date.  You should read the docs on Core Animation to learn how to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Ok, so setNeedsDisplay sets the flag, but later AppKit (?) can ignore this flag and view is not redrawn? (approx. in 2/3 of timer events)

Comment: I have a CoreGraphics calls here since in my app Cocoa is not enough for me and I'm using CoreGrapchis. NSTimer is not important here, in my real app timer is implemented not by me and in a different way, it's not even me who handles timer events, NSTimer here is only to do primitive "animation" and show that with -display it's slow.